# What is and how to calculate quartic interpolation?

Tags: interpolation

I was reading the [gist](https://gist.github.com/dfarhi/66ec9d760ae0c49a5c492c9fae93984a) on the reward function used in OpenAI Five, but I didn't understand the way they calculate health's reward.

This is what they state: *Hero health is scored according to a quartic interpolation between 0 (dead) and 1 (full health) to force heavier weight when the agent is near dying.*

I tried googling but didn't manage to find an easy enough explanation for me to understand. What exactly is *quartic interpolation* and how is it calculated?

I understand the normalization part of scoring it between 0 and 1, but how do they increase the weight of certain values?

Comment: I think the question is best suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, i'll try posting it there!